# Emgu CV does not detect CUDA

Tags: c#, opencv, nvidia, emgucv

I have GeForce GTX 960 with installed 353.90 NVidia driver and 7.5.18 CUDA driver. I'm using the latest version of Emgu CV, but it doesn't detect CUDA on the system (even in Emgu samples), `Emgu.CV.Cuda.CudaInvoke.HasCuda` is always `false`. At the same time other programs, like Xillisoft Video Converter can use CUDA without problems. How do I enable CUDA for Emgu CV?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're building an x64 app. If your build configuration is set to AnyCpu, uncheck the "Prefer 32 bit" box under Project properties -> Build. OpenCV has dropped support for x86 CUDA following NVIDIA CUDA v7.

Comment: this didn't work for me.  I am running a Microsoft Surface Book with the discrete GeForce GPU with 384 CUDA cores.  I also changed the NVIDIA graphics settings so that the geforce GPU works for all programs, but that didn't change the results.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this issue? I am running into the same thing.